# Profinet / Profibus linux

Tags: c++, linux

I want to start to do some programming of profinet in linux with C/C++ , which libraries must be used ?

I've find that some kernel driver must be used but there is nothing in the CentOS 6.5 repositories.

Only some youtube videos.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer elsewhere?

Comment: no answer , justo the youtube vídeos that i talked about

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I've found cards manufactured by people who have linux driver support but no actual library implementation.

Comment: but with the info you can use the kernel driver with ioctl,... does these cards include docs, source code,...

Comment: Hrm, it looks like they just updated their website and I can't seem to fine the linux drivers anymore. :(  It was at: http://www.hilscher.com.  It looks like openscada has some profinet support, but I don't really want to have to run an entire stack + eclipse just to talk profinet, I would prefer to use a C/C++ driver if possible.  I will update if I come across anything else.

Comment: Closest I have found is in Python: https://github.com/devkid/profinet

Answer (score 6):

You can use the p-net Profinet device stack for programming in C or C++. It is GPL-licensed and available at https://github.com/rtlabs-com/p-net

Use it from Linux or an RTOS. No special hardware is required, just a standard Ethernet interface.

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of p-net

Comment: It's licensed under GPL.  Does that mean people have to disclose their source?